# Unable to capture all values from 0x01-0x1F

Tags: c, posix, uefi

I am coding a DOS-inspired EFI operating system. I have the capture key part down, as you can see here:

```
#include "uefi/uefi.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    efi_input_key_t ch; // define ch as an efi input key
    char command[1024] = ""; // define the command variable as a buffer stored in memory with a size of 1024 bytes
    int len = 0; // define the length of the command

    while (1) {
        ST->BootServices->WaitForEvent(1, &(ST->ConIn->WaitForKey), NULL); // wait for key so keys arent printed forever
        ST->ConIn->ReadKeyStroke(ST->ConIn, &ch); // define ch as pressed key

        if (ch.ScanCode == 0x01) {
            // Check for Escape key and break the loop
            break;
        }

        printf("%c", ch.UnicodeChar); // print the character

        if (len < (sizeof(command) - 1)) {
            command[len] = ch.UnicodeChar; // add the character to the back
            command[len + 1] = '\0';  // Null-terminate the string
            len++;
        }
    }

    return 0; // after pressing ESC, exit the program and go to the UEFI shell
}
```

When I press ESC, it copies the previously typed character to the current cursor position, and when I set it to ENTER instead of ESC, upon pressing ENTER, it moves the cursor to the beginning. How can I fix this?

Comment: And what is it supposed to do when you press `ESC` and `ENTER`?

Comment: ESC is the beginning of an escape sequence, it shouldn't do anything by itself. The result of writing it will depend on what you write after it.

Comment: I want ESC to exit the program and I am planning on using ENTER to use commands.

Comment: @Barmar `ESC` as a user entry usually quits what the user is doing.

Comment: In this it isn't. I think what is happening is that it isn't capturing ESC and using the last character honestly, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I don't know anything about UEFI, but I suspect `if (ch.ScanCode == 0x01)` doesn't do what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong scan code, the [ESC scan code](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/Apx_B_Console.html#efi-simple-text-input-protocol-and-efi-simple-text-input-ex-protocol) is 0x17.

Answer (score 0):

I found out ENTER and ESC. The ESC scan code is 0x17, and ENTER has a scan code of 0x0 like a normal character but you can check for a UnicodeChar value of 0xd.